# How to get sublist from list of objects with condition like sum of a object property of object is less than or equal to threshold value using stream?

Tags: java, list, stream

I have List of Questions objects, having attribute QuestionId and QuestionMarks. I need to sublist Questions such that sum of QuestionMarks in sublist is equal to specific value. How can I do it using java stream?

Comment: Yes, you can do it. Give it a try.

Comment: Please show us what you've tried.

Comment: Can you post sample code of yours

Comment: Thanks , I have function which returns List of QuestionObjects.
Then I stored it as: 
List <Questions> Q;

int result = Q.stream().peek(o -> o.getQuestionMarks()).mapToInt(o -> o.getQuestionMarks()).sum();

from this I can get sum of all QuestionMarks of all Question Objects items in list, but I need to select objects (sublist of Questions) Having sum of marks equal to some value.

I am not sure How can I use when I do 

Q.stream().filter for testing sum condition.

Comment: I have tried this without using stream api like (filter, reduce), How can I achieve this using stream api ? 
int TotalMarks = 200;
int index = 10;int ctm=0;
List<Questions> Q = foo.getQuestion();  
ctm = Q.subList(0, index).stream().peek(o->o.getQuestionMark()).mapToInt(o->o.getQuestionMark()).sum();
       while(ct<=tm) {
           ct = Q.subList(0, index++).stream().peek(o->o.getQuestionMark()).mapToInt(o->o.getQuestionMark()).sum();
           System.out.println("CurrentTotalMarks=" + ct);
       }
       System.out.println("TotalMarks=" + ct);
       return Q.subList(0, index);